# Custom field type with imagefield

Tags: 7, forms, media

I'm creating a widget with an image field. But I keep writing 0 to the database. But i need the fid to be saved. I know I can manipulate the data with hook_field_presave(). But the items array only contains image => '0'.

mymodule.module

```
/**
* Implements hook_field_widget_form().
*/
function mymodule_field_widget_form(&$form, &$form_state, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $delta, $element) {
...
  $element['image'] = array(
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#name' => 'mymodule_custom_image',
    '#title' => t('Image'),
    '#size' => 40,
    '#description' => t(""),
    '#upload_location' => 'public://',
    '#theme' => 'mymodule_custom_thumb_upload',
  ); 
...
}
```

Edit:

```
/**
* Implements hook_field_widget_info().
*/
function mymodule_field_widget_info() {
  return array(
    'mymodule_polygone_widget' => array(
      'label' => t('Default'),
      'field types' => array('mymodule_polygone'),
    ),
  );
}
```

mymodule.install

```
/*
* Implements hook_field_schema().
*/
function mymodule_field_schema($field) {
  $columns = array(
    'image' => array('type' => 'varchar', 'length' => 255, 'not null' => TRUE),
    'zones' => array('type' => 'text'),
  );

  return array(
    'columns' => $columns,
    'indexes' => array(),
  );
}
```

Comment: On your hook_field_widget_info() function what do you have as your return statement? This actually matters

Comment: Added the code :).

Comment: Well I apologize, I meant what is the return on your hook_field_widget_form not info. I'm sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it: Forgot the 'input ...' in my custom theme function :).

```
function theme_mymodule_thumb_upload($variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];

  if (isset($element['#file']->uri)) {
      $output = '<div id="edit-logo-ajax-wrapper"><div class="form-item form-type-managed-file form-item-logo"><span class="file">';
      $output .= '<img src="' . file_create_url($element['#file']->uri) . '" />';
      $output .= '</span><input type="submit" id="edit-' . $element['#name'] . '-remove-button" name="' . $element['#name'] . '_remove_button" value="Remove" class="form-submit ajax-processed">';
      $output .= '<input type="hidden" name="' . $element['#name'] . '[fid]" value="' . $element['#file']->fid . '">';

      return $output;
  }
}
```